# How do I get this WPF .gif to play on update? 

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, animated-gif

**Question:**

- Why does my `.gif` load, but not play when updating using `GifSourcePropertyChanged`?

**About `.gif` loading:**
Currently I have use `U.IsValidURL()` to keep `new Uri` from throwing an `Exception`. This is because I need `GifImage` to load with the application and then update later from `ViewModel`. Everything goes fine until `GifSourcePropertyChanged` is called, then `local:GifImage` is updated, but the `.gif` doesn't play (I believe it loads as `MediaElement` loads in parallel and `local:GifImage` turns black where the `.gif` is suppose to load). If I hard code a sample `Uri` from the beginning, `local:GifImage` loads and plays just fine.

**Example XAML:**

```
<local:GifImage 
        GifSource="{    
            Binding Path=myGifImage, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
            Mode=OneWay}"
        AutoStart="True"/>
```

**Example ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{                   
    private string _myGifImage; 

    public string myGifImage
    {
        get { return this._myGifImage; }
        set
        {
            this._myGifImage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("myGifImage");
        }
    }
}
```

**Example GifImage Class:**

```
public class GifImage : Image
{
    #region Memmbers

    private GifBitmapDecoder _gifDecoder;
    private Int32Animation _animation;
    private bool _isInitialized;

    #endregion Memmbers

    #region Properties

    private int FrameIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(FrameIndexProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FrameIndexProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty FrameIndexProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("FrameIndex", typeof(int), typeof(GifImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(ChangingFrameIndex)));

    private static void ChangingFrameIndex(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ev)
    {
        GifImage image = obj as GifImage;
        image.Source = image._gifDecoder.Frames[(int)ev.NewValue];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines whether the animation starts on it's own
    /// </summary>
    public bool AutoStart
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AutoStartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutoStartProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoStartProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("AutoStart", typeof(bool), typeof(GifImage), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, AutoStartPropertyChanged));

    private static void AutoStartPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            (sender as GifImage).StartAnimation();
    }

    public string GifSource
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(GifSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GifSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GifSourceProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("GifSource", typeof(string), typeof(GifImage), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, GifSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static void GifSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // CARLO 20100622: Reinitialize animation everytime image is changed
        (sender as GifImage).Initialize();
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Private Instance Methods

    private void Initialize()
    {

        if (U.IsValidURL(this.GifSource, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            _gifDecoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(
                new Uri(this.GifSource),
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            _animation = new Int32Animation(0, _gifDecoder.Frames.Count - 1, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, _gifDecoder.Frames.Count / 10, (int)((_gifDecoder.Frames.Count / 10.0 - _gifDecoder.Frames.Count / 10) * 1000))));
            _animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            this.Source = _gifDecoder.Frames[0];

            _isInitialized = true;
        }

    }

    #endregion Private Instance Methods

    #region Public Instance Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows and starts the gif animation
    /// </summary>
    public void Show()
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.StartAnimation();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hides and stops the gif animation
    /// </summary>
    public void Hide()
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.StopAnimation();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StartAnimation()
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
            this.Initialize();

        BeginAnimation(FrameIndexProperty, _animation);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StopAnimation()
    {
        BeginAnimation(FrameIndexProperty, null);
    }

    #endregion Public Instance Methods
}
```

I got `GifImage` from somewhere on SO (I can't remember which question, there are several on `WPF` and `.gifs`). `GifImage` was the only class that didn't have a ton of errors (at least for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is with your code, but you could try to use [this attached property](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/27/wpf-display-an-animated-gif-image/) instead:

```
<Image my:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding Path=myGifImage}"/>
```

Comment: Hmm... looks interesting. That's actually one article I haven't seen yet. I'll go take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Well that actually plays the `.gif` now. Image quality is still incredibly poor (might be a bit worse). It's similar to tv static with an out of focus lense. The article also says the frame deal has a limited platform (7 and vista). I'm not sure I can use this because of that. What happens on platforms that don't have the update?

Comment: This is odd... when I remove the `GifImage` class and `local:GifImage`, the new code stops working.

Comment: If you're not on Win7 it will just use a defaut frame duration of 100ms (like GifImage). I don't know why the quality is poor, I don't have that issue (perhaps the image itself has poor quality?). I don't see how it could be related with GifImage anyway... you can use the attached property on a normal Image control, you don't need GifImage at all

Comment: Yep, I got it setup exactly as in your blog. Easy cut & paste job. I'll post a screenshot of the image quality difference in a minute.

Comment: Images added. The poor quality happens with any custom control I use.

Comment: weird... it doesn't happen on my computer

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code works great. I just have to sort out a small bug. For some reason when the `.gif` is loaded for the first time, it doesn't play, but it will start playing if I update it a second time. I watch it in the debugger, somehow `var decoder = GetDecoder(source) as GifBitmapDecoder;` ends up being `null` even though it returned a `BitmapDecoder` from `GetDecoder`.